# Alarm without message dialog

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, message, alarm

I would like to make and App that when users set an alarm (like wake up alarm) and alarms sounds, doesnt show a message dialog to confirm and stop the alarm.

On web I have discovered some methods called `Obscured` and `UnObscured` that fired when the message's alarm shows, but the message still showed!

In Code:

```
        public OverAlarmPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PhoneApplicationFrame phoneAppRootFrame = (Application.Current as App).RootFrame;
        phoneAppRootFrame.Obscured += OnObscured;
        phoneAppRootFrame.Unobscured += Unobscured;
    }



    void OnObscured(Object sender, ObscuredEventArgs e)
    {
        txtStatus.Text = "Obscured event occurred";
    }

    void Unobscured(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtStatus.Text = "Unobscured event occurred";
    }
```

I just want to make stop the alarm sound with the vibrating of mobile (with gyroscope) but without the hell message!

There are any solution or is this a O.S feature that i cant touch?

Answer (score 0):

The built in notification classes (Alarm and Reminder) don't support any customization of the UI that is displayed when they are triggered.

The only alternative I can think of would require the application to remain running (possibly under the lock screen) and then you just play the sound from the app at the appropriate time.
Obviously this requires that the app remain running though.
Other than that you will be prevented from trying to create the behaviour you are after.